# ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta - Default Model Binder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm experiencing some different behavior after switching from ASP.NET MVC 1.0 to ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta. I checked the breaking changes but it's not clear where the issue lies.

The problem has to do with the default model binder and a model that implements IDataErrorInfo.

The property (IDataErrorInfo.Item):

```
public string this[string columnName]
```

is no longer being called for each property. What am I missing?

Comment: If is duplicate of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760039/is-idataerrorinfo-ignored-during-model-validation-in-mvc-2

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an answer. The validation works but it behaves differently. In my case for simple types such as System.Nullable<int>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further debugging work I believe I understand why in my particular case the `IDataErrorInfo.Item` isn't being called. The following code is used in the ASP.NET MVC 2 Beta to validate an `IDataErrorInfo` property:

```
internal sealed class DataErrorInfoPropertyModelValidator : ModelValidator
{
    public DataErrorInfoPropertyModelValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext controllerContext)
        : base(metadata, controllerContext)
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
    {
        if (Metadata.Model != null)
        {
            var castContainer = container as IDataErrorInfo;
            if (castContainer != null)
            {
                string errorMessage = castContainer[Metadata.PropertyName];
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
                {
                    return new[] { new ModelValidationResult { Message = errorMessage } };
                }
            }
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidationResult>();
    }
}
```

My model contains a property that is `System.Nullable<int>` and when the model binder binds an empty string from the HTML post, the `Metadata.Model` is equal to null, thus the validation doesn't run.

This is fundamentally different from ASP.NET MVC 1.0, where this scenario fires the validator all the way through to a call to `IDataErrorInfo.Item`.

Am I just not using something the way it was intended?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this.  I talked with some of the other MVC devs, and we suspect the null check served a purpose at some point between Preview 2 and Beta but has since been rendered unnecessary.  I filed a bug to remove the check.

Comment: I appreciate you looking into this!

Answer (score 1):

DefaultModelBinder in MVC 1.0:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyValidated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
{
    IDataErrorInfo model = bindingContext.Model as IDataErrorInfo;
    if (model != null)
    {
        string str = model[propertyDescriptor.Name];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            string key = CreateSubPropertyName(bindingContext.ModelName, propertyDescriptor.Name);
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(key, str);
        }
    }
}
```

DefaultModelBinder in MVC 2.0 beta:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyValidated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
{
    ModelMetadata metadata = bindingContext.PropertyMetadata[propertyDescriptor.Name];
    metadata.Model = value;
    string prefix = CreateSubPropertyName(bindingContext.ModelName, metadata.PropertyName);
    foreach (ModelValidator validator in metadata.GetValidators(controllerContext))
    {
        foreach (ModelValidationResult result in validator.Validate(bindingContext.Model))
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(CreateSubPropertyName(prefix, result.MemberName), result.Message);
        }
    }
    if ((bindingContext.ModelState.IsValidField(prefix) && (value == null)) && !TypeHelpers.TypeAllowsNullValue(propertyDescriptor.PropertyType))
    {
        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(prefix, GetValueRequiredResource(controllerContext));
    }
}
```

It doesn't use IDataErrorInfo this[string columnName] property... Seems like a bug, because DefaultModelBinder still uses Error property. It is inconsistency at least.

**EDIT**

I used reflector and noticed that DataErrorInfoPropertyModelValidator doesn't seem to be used, so I created my own class:

```
public class DataErrorInfoModelPropertyValidatorProvider : ModelValidatorProvider
{
    // Methods
    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (metadata == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("metadata");
        }
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        var validators = new List<ModelValidator>();
        validators.Add(new DataErrorInfoPropertyModelValidator(metadata, context));
        return validators;
    }

    internal sealed class DataErrorInfoPropertyModelValidator : ModelValidator
    {
        // Methods
        public DataErrorInfoPropertyModelValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext controllerContext)
            : base(metadata, controllerContext)
        {
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
        {
            if (container != null)
            {
                IDataErrorInfo info = container as IDataErrorInfo;
                if (info != null)
                {
                    string str = info[Metadata.PropertyName];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                    {
                        ModelValidationResult[] resultArray = new ModelValidationResult[1];
                        ModelValidationResult result = new ModelValidationResult();
                        result.Message = str;
                        resultArray[0] = result;
                        return resultArray;
                    }
                }
            }
            return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidationResult>();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I used:

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new DataErrorInfoModelPropertyValidatorProvider());
```

And it works:) This is just temporary solution. Will have to be corrected in final MVC 2.

**EDIT**

I also changed `if (base.Metadata.Model != null)` to if (container != null) in `Validate()` method of `DataErrorInfoPropertyModelValidator`.

Comment: The call to metaData.GetValidators should yield a DataErrorInfoPropertyModelValidator. Calling its Validate should result in a direct call to the IDataErrorInfo interface. It just doesn't seem to be making it that far.